# Uninstalled Pyton 2.7, now I cant log in

Tags: python, python-2.7

I uninstalled python using following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove python2.7
```

It ended up removing lot of related system files as well. Now when ubuntu boots up it prompts me login, but after that it fails. How can I fix this?

Comment: That was a terrible, terrible, idea. Ubuntu replies on Python for quite a few things.

Answer (score 1):

Open a tty (Ctrl+ALt+F1) and login. Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop.
```